# Как настроить отправку ответных сообщений, которые видит только пользователь, вызвавший команду? Discord py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Хочу сделать, чтобы бот отправлял ответное сообщение, которое видит только один пользователь

[image]

Мой код:

```
@bot.slash_command(name='namecard', description = "отправляет выбранный баннер")
async def banner(ctx, категория: str, название: str):
  pic2 = название + ".png"
  await ctx.defer()
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  await ctx.respond(f'Баннер **«{название}»**', file=discord.File(f'General/NameCard/{категория}/{pic2}'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо добавить условие `ephemeral`.

`ephemeral=True` - видно только одному пользователю.

`ephemeral=False` - видно всем.

В вашем случае:

```
  await ctx.respond(f'Баннер **«{название}»**', file=discord.File(f'General/NameCard/{категория}/{pic2}'), ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Это правда мне помогло!

Answer (score 0):

`await interaction.response.send_message(f'Баннер **«{название}»**', file=discord.File(f'General/NameCard/{категория}/{pic2}'), ephemeral=True)`

Более подробно в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message)